# How to extend an existing rule in MS Build?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

it's probably a stupid question, but I have wasted a lot of time.

I found this one and several other links where people are editing .xml, .props and .targets file to create a customization in Visual Studio build.

[Adding new target to use ClCompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856373/pre-processing-c-file-using-msbuild-and-visual-studio-2012)

Here he/she is extending CL rule in xml file and doing other things in .props and .targets file.

But as I am referring to MSBuild documentations, I cannot find a way to customize using these three files. I only found creating a custom target in .vcxproj file. However, when I try to extend a rule here, it just says

> Rule is not an element of Project.

These are related documentations I found -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-add-custom-build-tools-to-msbuild-projects?view=vs-2019

Has methods of adding customization changed or am I not referring to right documentations? Please help. Basically, I want to do what has been done in above stack overflow answer. (Create a preprocessing target which can get all properties/items of CLCompile target.)

Comment: You can check: [Property Page XML rule files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/property-page-xml-files?view=vs-2019). As this document indicates, the related XML rule files usually store in “1033” folder, which is under this path `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\[version number]\[VS version]\IDE\VC\VCTargets\1033`. You may need to create(customize) a new XML file or change some related xml codes in this folder.

Comment: Besides, for `.prop` file and `.targets` file, please check the `VCTargets` folder(one level up from the 1033 folder) and [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=vs-2019#property-sheet-layout). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I needed something where I don't have to change/add internal visual studio files. Something in my project folder only. I tried adding xml there like the ones in 1033 but didn't work.

Comment: Hi, I think it is not possible if you just modify codes in `.vcxproj` file. As the doc mentioned each rule is populated from an .xml file in the VCTargets folder, you should create your own xml file in “1033” folder and `.prop`, `.targets` file in VCTargets folder, then configure them well, after that see if they work.

Comment: Book "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine"  From properties sheets you can override existing targets, and invoke a custom xml file as needed.  Using the Properties Manager and properties sheets allows you to override all project behavior on a target build system.
I'm currently working on a similar problem, and once I have the full trail of breadcrumbs perhaps I can submit an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to override ClCompile target by adding ClCompile.props and added my custom task in it by using Exec Command. It served my purpose and I didn't actually go through extending xml file.